# HP iLO2/3 cli: send NMI

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I want to send a Non-Maskable Interrupt (NMI) to the system over the HP iLO2/3 cli. Unfortunately I don't know the correct syntax or target:

hpiLO-> nmi

`status=2
status_tag=COMMAND PROCESSING FAILED
error_tag=COMMAND SYNTAX ERROR
You must specify an NMI target.`

Maybe you can help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `nmi server` at the "hpiLO->" prompt to generate an NMI to the system via the CLI.

"server" is the target requested in the error message you posted.

Comment: thank you, it works. The help page only displayed '/system1' and '/map1' as targets...